# android make custom layout shape

Tags: android, layout, shapes, viewgroup

I'm trying to make custom ViewGroup layout shapes, that the layout be star or heart, triangles or even make the lines diagonal.

So the the goal is to make collage view for two or more ImageViews.
[image: triangle layouts]

[image: hearts layouts]

Could someone give me a library or a way to do this trick?

Comment: There is not an easy way to do this with "ImageViews" your option is to use Canvas.

Comment: I don't want to apply this on ImageViews, I want to do this for ViewGroups.

Comment: @MarwanZakariya are u able to get the ans of it looks cool if it is implemented

Answer (score 10):

You can achieve this by using standard methods of `Canvas` and `BitmapShader`.

First method could look like this:

```
@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //bitmap 01
    canvas.save(Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.clipPath(shape01);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap01, 0, 0, paint);
    canvas.restore();

    //bitmap 02
    canvas.save(Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.clipPath(shape02);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap02, 0, 0, paint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

The second could look like this:

```
BitmapShader shader01 = new BitmapShader(bitmap01, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
BitmapShader shader02 = new BitmapShader(bitmap02, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
Paint paint01 = new Paint();
Paint paint02 = new Paint();
paint01.setShader(shader01);
paint02.setShader(shader02);

@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //bitmap 01
    canvas.drawPath(path01, paint01);

    //bitmap 02
    canvas.drawPath(path02, paint02);
}
```

So you need to define your shapes, load bitmaps and draw them.